# Did erlang 21.3 install correctly?

Tags: ubuntu, erlang

I have attempted to install `erlang 21.3` from source . There were no apparent/obvious errors but I still see version 20.

The source was downloaded and installed:

```
wget -O - "https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/gpgkey" | sudo apt-key add -
wget http://erlang.org/download/otp_src_21.3.tar.gz
cd otp_src_21.3
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

From the installation there are  hundreds of lines like the following

```
/otp_src_21.3/lib/ftp'
test -d "/usr/local/lib/erlang/releases/21" || mkdir -p "/usr/local/lib/erlang/releases/21" ;           \
if test ! -f "/usr/local/lib/erlang/releases/21/installed_application_versions" ; then              \
 echo "ftp-1.0.2" > "/usr/local/lib/erlang/releases/21/installed_application_versions" || exit 1;   \
else                                \
 if test x = x`grep ftp-1.0.2 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/releases/21/installed_application_versions"` ; then \
  echo ftp-1.0.2 >> "/usr/local/lib/erlang/releases/21/installed_application_versions" || exit 1;   \
 fi ;                               \
fi
make[3]: Leaving directory '/shared/otp_src_21.3/lib/ftp'
=== Leaving application ftp
make[2]: Leaving directory '/shared/otp_src_21.3/lib/ftp'
make[2]: Entering directory '/shared/otp_src_21.3/lib/tftp'
=== Entering application tftp
make[3]: Entering directory '/shared/otp_src_21.3/lib/tftp/src'
make -w RELEASE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/erlang"   release_spec
make[4]: Entering directory '/shared/otp_src_21.3/lib/tftp/src'
/usr/bin/install -c -d "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/tftp-1.0.1/src"
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 tftp.erl tftp_app.erl tftp_binary.erl tftp_engine.erl tftp_file.erl tftp_lib.erl tftp_logger.erl tftp_sup.erl  tftp.hrl "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/tftp-1.0.1/src"
/usr/bin/install -c -d "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/tftp-1.0.1/ebin"
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644  ../ebin/tftp.beam ../ebin/tftp_app.beam ../ebin/tftp_binary.beam ../ebin/tftp_engine.beam ../ebin/tftp_file.beam ../ebin/tftp_lib.beam ../ebin/tftp_logger.beam ../ebin/tftp_sup.beam ../ebin/tftp.app \
../ebin/tftp.appup "/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/tftp-1.0.1/ebin"
make[4]: Leaving directory '/shared/otp_src_21.3/lib/tftp/src'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/shared/otp_src_21.3/lib/tftp/src'
make[3]: Entering directory '/shared/otp_src_21.3/lib/tftp/doc/src'
make -w RELEASE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/erlang"   release_spec
make[4]: Entering directory '/shared/otp_src_21.3/lib/tftp/doc/src'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'release_spec'.
make[4]: Leaving directory '/shared/otp_src_21.3/lib/tftp/doc/src'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/shared/otp_src_21.3/lib/tftp/doc/src'
make[3]: Entering directory '/shared/otp_src_21.3/lib/tftp'
test -d "/usr/local/lib/erlang/releases/21" || mkdir -p "/usr/local/lib/erlang/releases/21" ;           \
if test ! -f "/usr/local/lib/erlang/releases/21/installed_application_versions" ; then              \
 echo "tftp-1.0.1" > "/usr/local/lib/erlang/releases/21/installed_application_versions" || exit 1;  \
else                                \
 if test x = x`grep tftp-1.0.1 "/usr/local/lib/erlang/releases/21/installed_application_versions"` ; then \
  echo tftp-1.0.1 >> "/usr/local/lib/erlang/releases/21/installed_application_versions" || exit 1;  \
 fi ;                               \
fi
make[3]: Leaving directory '/shared/otp_src_21.3/lib/tftp'
=== Leaving application tftp
make[2]: Leaving directory '/shared/otp_src_21.3/lib/tftp'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/shared/otp_src_21.3/lib'
```

Then at the very end the following:

```
(cd "/usr/local/lib/erlang" \
 && ./Install  -minimal "/usr/local/lib/erlang")

/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 "/shared/otp_src_21.3/OTP_VERSION" "/usr/local/lib/erlang/releases/21"
cd /usr/local/bin
rm -f erl
rm -f erlc
rm -f epmd
rm -f run_erl
rm -f to_erl
rm -f dialyzer
rm -f typer
rm -f escript
rm -f ct_run
ln -s ../lib/erlang/bin/erl erl
ln -s ../lib/erlang/bin/erlc erlc
ln -s ../lib/erlang/bin/epmd epmd
ln -s ../lib/erlang/bin/run_erl run_erl
ln -s ../lib/erlang/bin/to_erl to_erl
ln -s ../lib/erlang/bin/dialyzer dialyzer
ln -s ../lib/erlang/bin/typer typer
ln -s ../lib/erlang/bin/escript escript
ln -s ../lib/erlang/bin/ct_run ct_run
```

The `erlang` did get installed it seems: the following is exactly current date:

```
$ ls -lrta $(which erlc)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Dec 27 00:49 /usr/local/bin/erlc -> ../lib/erlang/bin/erlc
```

But the version of `erlang` is still the system default:

```
erl -eval 'erlang:display(erlang:system_info(otp_release)), halt().'  -noshell
"20"
```

So .. did it install actually? If not is there some link missing?  This is on `ubuntu 18.0.4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overwriting the `erl` in another `bin` location fixed this.

```
 sudo rm /usr/bin/erl
 sudo ln -s $(pwd)/erl /usr/bin/erl
```

Now we can see the correct version:

```
$ erl -eval 'erlang:display(erlang:system_info(otp_release)), halt().'  -noshell
"21"
```

Comment: Note that this is not considered good practice, as the package manager will 'fix' it the next time the system-installed Erlang package is updated (or remove it if that package is uninstalled). You're better off just adding the location you installed to to `$PATH`.

Comment: @AustinHeemgarn That makes sense . thx for the tip